# outlier replacement with their mean for multi-layered data in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, outliers

My df with different customer's along with their sales data, but there are some outliers and I would like to replace outliers(which are above 2 SD below the mean)(μ ± 2σ) and replace them with their each customer_id mean.

```
structure(list(Date = c("6/29/2014", "7/6/2014", "7/13/2014", 
"7/20/2014", "7/27/2014", "8/3/2014", "8/10/2014", "8/17/2014", 
"8/24/2014", "6/29/2014", "7/6/2014", "7/13/2014", "7/20/2014", 
"7/27/2014", "8/3/2014", "8/10/2014", "8/17/2014", "8/24/2014", 
"7/6/2014", "7/13/2014", "7/20/2014", "7/27/2014", "8/3/2014", 
"8/10/2014", "8/17/2014", "8/24/2014"), customer_id = c("9000A", 
"9000A", "9000A", "9000A", "9000A", "9000A", "9000A", "9000A", 
"9000A", "80A09", "80A09", "80A09", "80A09", "80A09", "80A09", 
"80A09", "80A09", "80A09", "Y90BC", "Y90BC", "Y90BC", "Y90BC", 
"Y90BC", "Y90BC", "Y90BC", "Y90BC"), sales = c(20L, 40L, 0L, 
42L, 56L, 90L, 500L, 23L, 60L, 200L, 234L, 500L, 450L, 0L, 900L, 
459L, 347L, 895L, 380L, 390L, 432L, 320L, 400L, 10L, 0L, 1000L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))
```

Can some one help me probably using dplyr.
Note : all '0' values and sales which are not in (μ ± 2σ) needs to be replaced with mean values respected to their customer_id

Comment: What do you mean by "replace them with their customer_id mean"? Which column do you want to replace?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Each customer has different sales mean.If customer 1 has a sales values which is outside of (μ ± 2σ) then that sales value needs to be replaced with mean of that particular customer 1@otwtm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And another way with dplyr :)

wasn't fully sure if you want the cutoff to be based on global mean or grouped by customer, so there are 2 versions.

edit: to check for < mean - 2sd  and also != 0 you have to change the first argument of the ifelse to

```
sales > mean(sales) + 2*sd(sales) | sales < mean(sales) - 2*sd(sales) | sales == 0
```

code

```
# version to check for > global mean + 2 * global sd
# if sales-value > global cutoff sales-value gets replaced by customer mean
test_data2 = 
  test_data %>% group_by(customer_id) %>% 
  mutate(sales = ifelse(sales > mean(test_data$sales) + 2*sd(test_data$sales), mean(sales), sales))

# version to check for mean per customer + 2 * sd per customer
# if sales-value > customer cutoff sales-value gets replaced by customer mean
test_data2 = 
  test_data %>% group_by(customer_id) %>% 
  mutate(sales = ifelse(sales > mean(sales) + 2*sd(sales), mean(sales), sales))



### check if this is what we want

# calc global mean + global sd + cutoff global
mean(test_data$sales)
sd(test_data$sales)
mean(test_data$sales) + 2*sd(test_data$sales)

# calc mean, sd, cutoff for each customer
test_data %>% group_by(customer_id) %>% summarise(mean = mean(sales), sd = sd(sales), cutoff = mean + 2*sd(sales))



test_data$sales2 = test_data2$sales

test_data %>% filter(customer_id == "80A09")
test_data %>% filter(customer_id == "9000A")
test_data %>% filter(customer_id == "Y90BC")
```

separate control-code to get no inference between both versions:

```
df = structure(list(Date = c("6/29/2014", "7/6/2014", "7/13/2014", 
                                    "7/20/2014", "7/27/2014", "8/3/2014", "8/10/2014", "8/17/2014", 
                                    "8/24/2014", "6/29/2014", "7/6/2014", "7/13/2014", "7/20/2014", 
                                    "7/27/2014", "8/3/2014", "8/10/2014", "8/17/2014", "8/24/2014", 
                                    "7/6/2014", "7/13/2014", "7/20/2014", "7/27/2014", "8/3/2014", 
                                    "8/10/2014", "8/17/2014", "8/24/2014"), customer_id = c("9000A", 
                                                                                            "9000A", "9000A", "9000A", "9000A", "9000A", "9000A", "9000A", 
                                                                                            "9000A", "80A09", "80A09", "80A09", "80A09", "80A09", "80A09", 
                                                                                            "80A09", "80A09", "80A09", "Y90BC", "Y90BC", "Y90BC", "Y90BC", 
                                                                                            "Y90BC", "Y90BC", "Y90BC", "Y90BC"), sales = c(20L, 40L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                           42L, 56L, 90L, 500L, 23L, 60L, 200L, 234L, 500L, 450L, 0L, 900L, 
                                                                                                                                           459L, 347L, 895L, 380L, 390L, 432L, 320L, 400L, 10L, 0L, 1000L
                                                                                            )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))



test_data = df %>% group_by(customer_id) %>% mutate(sales =ifelse( sales > mean(sales) + 2*sd(sales) | sales < mean(sales) - 2*sd(sales) | sales == 0,mean(sales),sales))
test_data$sales_old = df$sales

df %>% group_by(customer_id) %>% summarise(mean = mean(sales), sd = sd(sales), cutoff = mean + 2*sd(sales))


test_data %>% filter(customer_id == "80A09" & sales != sales_old)
test_data %>% filter(customer_id == "9000A" & sales != sales_old)
test_data %>% filter(customer_id == "Y90BC" & sales != sales_old)
```

output:

```
> df %>% group_by(customer_id) %>% summarise(mean = mean(sales), sd = sd(sales), cutoff = mean + 2*sd(sales))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  customer_id  mean    sd cutoff
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 80A09       443.   301.  1045.
2 9000A        92.3  155.   402.
3 Y90BC       366.   310.   986.
> test_data %>% filter(customer_id == "80A09" & sales != sales_old)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   customer_id [1]
  Date      customer_id sales sales_old
  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>     <int>
1 7/27/2014 80A09        443.         0
> test_data %>% filter(customer_id == "9000A" & sales != sales_old)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   customer_id [1]
  Date      customer_id sales sales_old
  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>     <int>
1 7/13/2014 9000A        92.3         0
2 8/10/2014 9000A        92.3       500
> test_data %>% filter(customer_id == "Y90BC" & sales != sales_old)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   customer_id [1]
  Date      customer_id sales sales_old
  <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>     <int>
1 8/17/2014 Y90BC        366.         0
2 8/24/2014 Y90BC        366.      1000
```

Comment: `test_data = 
  df %>% group_by(customer_id) %>% 
  mutate(sales =ifelse( sales > mean(sales) + 2*sd(sales) | sales < mean(sales) - 2*sd(sales) | sales == 0,mean(sales),sales))` I tried this but it is replacing with global mean other than the customer mean.

Comment: hmm, strange. Could you try it again, because for me it is working as intended. Maybe some inference with the other version?